# why does my jquery alert, only works when firebug persist is clicked?

Tags: jquery

heres my code:

```
$('#approve').click(function(){
            var p_id=$('#propid').val();            
            var para={          
                pid_r:p_id
                };
                var postdata=$.param(para)+'&'+$('[name="scripts[]"]:checked').serialize();
                $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"listofres-valid.php",
                data:postdata,
                success: function(data){                            
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#findtable').find('#removed').hide();
                    alert("Approved");

                    }
                });
            });
```

i want to alert "approved" when the update is successful

Comment: very vague question. to say the least :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Firebug is not active, the console does not exist, hence calling console.log will result in an error and halt the script.

Comment: cheers! i've been pondering over the same thing a year back and if I knew about SO I could have spent 30 minutes less debugging code :>

Answer (score 4):

The problem is likely with the `console.log` call.  Remove that and see if it works without Firebug.